# Accessing Model in utility in laravel

Tags: laravel-5, cron

I'm trying to access the User model in a utility I built that will eventually send emails out, this is being triggered with by cron, and I'm using php artisan schedule:run to test it. Below is the utility I'm starting to build out, and currently when test it I am getting 'I was triggered'. This is being triggered by a registered console command. Thats all working.

```
<?php
namespace App\Utility;

use Log;
use Mail;
use App\User;

class ReferralProgramUtility
{

    static public function test()
    {   
        LOG::info("I was triggered");
    }
}
```

However, when I change this to pull in the User model....

```
<?php
namespace App\Utility;

use Log;
use Mail;
use App\User;

class ReferralProgramUtility
{

    static public function test()
    {   
        $user = User::all();
        LOG::info($user);
    }
}
```

I get the following error....

#### Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/appname/app/User.php:32

I'm using another utility that has a similar configuration and uses the User model and this work fine, the only difference is that this is on is being triggered by task scheduler. Not sure what is causing this, and I'm fairly new to Laravel so any tips or recommendation would be hugely appreciated. Thanks, in advance.

Comment: What's on line 32 of User.php (UserMOdel)?

Comment: public function getDisabledAtAttribute($value)
    {
        return Carbon::createFromTimestamp(Carbon::parse($value)->getTimestamp())->timezone(Auth::user()->timezone)->toDateTimeString();
    }

Comment: If I use LOG::info(gettype($user)); its an object.

Comment: well, you are getting this error because `Auth::user()` is null

Comment: LOG::info(gettype($user)); is object because it's an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection class, you can check that using LOG::info(get_class($user));

Comment: Thanks, for your reply. So what would be the best way to access a collection at this point in the application if a user isn't logged in and its happening behind the scene. Thanks, again for clearing things up.

Comment: You can access the collection, as long as you are not accessing "disabled_at" property of a user. As an example can use `LOG::info($user->first()->name)` if you there is name column in your table. but you can't output entire user object

Comment: Again, thanks for your help. So I wouldn't be able to loop over the collection to compare a column value to something?

Comment: You should be able to loop through the collection without an issue, the error occurs when you outputs user object with "disabled_at" attribute.